# Basement flooding

Tags: waterproofing, flooding

I live in a raised ranch with a downward sloping driveway. This year we experienced a major flood with all water coming under the garage door. Does a waterproof garage door exist? Once the water got into the garage it seeped into the house through the door to the house.

Comment: Probably if you have a million lying around.  Will be much cheaper to improve the drainage.  Water runs downhill.  Adding a sump pit and pump in the garage should help to keep water from the house.

Comment: Cut a drainage channel across the front of the garage door and either drain it by gravity around the side of the garage or install a  sump pump. A steel or aluminum grate over the channel would allow vehicles ingress/egress.

Comment: A sufficiently tall speed bump is a drainage channel alternative if there's nowhere low to drain the water.

Comment: A waterproof garage door would have to be massively strong. I don't think anyone makes one, but if you have deep pockets automatic self-deploying flood barriers exist. They also have to be massively strong, but they don't *also* have to be a garage door. They won't be inexpensive.

Comment: Probably use a speed bump and put a channel in front of it.  But if its an extreme weather event that you are trying to cope with it, it may not be enough.

Comment: A picture here would help to inspire real answers. What is the grading like around the house? Is there a place to divert the water around the side? Or is the driveway cut into the ground with a retaining wall on the outside edge? What is the garage elevation compared to the living floors of the house?

Comment: @popham, that depends whether the speed bump *has* somewhere lower than the garage to drain the water.  If the garage is the lowest point, i.e. the space to the sides of the driveway slope up, a berm won't help.  I imagine the best solution in that situation would be some kind of trench drain at the lowest point, draining to a sump pit with a pump.  Hopefull the pump would have somewhere it could drain.

Comment: @Huesmann, the speed bump could function as a dam with a pond of water on the other side. The maximum useful height in your hypothetical would be the height of the side slopes. If the driveway slopes down toward the house, then I would concede that pumping is necessary, but that wasn't my understanding of the OP's description. This reminded me of https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3637271/amp/Texas-man-uses-dam-filled-WATER-house-dry-27-inch-flood.html.

Comment: @popham it all depends on the quantity of water one must deal with, and the geometry of the driveway, none of which has been provided, except "downward sloping."